# Multiple Regression Effect Size, Significance, and Cohens f^2

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, effect-size

I have a multiple regression with a continuous dependent variable, 1 continuous independent variable, and a handful of binary independent variables. The R summary is pasted below:

```
Coefficients:
                                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                             28.650948   0.422146  67.870  < 2e-16 ***
age                                    -0.190294   0.002482 -76.664  < 2e-16 ***
sexMale                                -1.882749   0.070134 -26.845  < 2e-16 ***
AAA_TRUE                                        -0.339332   0.079563  -4.265 2.00e-05 ***
hTRUE                                  -0.475690   0.145306  -3.274 0.001062 ** 
lTRUE                                  -0.663973   0.100555  -6.603 4.06e-11 ***
dTRUE                                   0.341724   0.165669   2.063 0.039147 *  
cTRUE                                   0.045918   0.169017   0.272 0.785874    
d2TRUE                                  0.222338   0.161980   1.373 0.169874    
d2TRUE                                 -0.166166   0.147749  -1.125 0.260742    
h2TRUE                                 -0.276585   0.197072  -1.403 0.160482    
h3TRUE                                 -0.111114   0.099086  -1.121 0.262124    
l2TRUE                                 -0.739833   0.452689  -1.634 0.102199    
sTRUE                                  -1.018127   0.381612  -2.668 0.007633 ** 
s2TRUE                                 -0.646916   0.124342  -5.203 1.97e-07 ***

...

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.053 on 64769 degrees of freedom
  (1341 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1796,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1792 
F-statistic: 488.8 on 29 and 64769 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

A variable of interest is `AAA_TRUE` which is significant and tells me all things held constant, being true for that variable results in a -0.3 change in the dependent variable. However, if I look at the effect size (Cohens f^2) it is extremely small (~ 5e-7). The r-squared of the model without `AAA_TRUE` is barely smaller than the r-squared when including it. I'm trying to wrap my head around how a significant variable with what appears to be a decent sized coefficient explains such a small amount of the variance explained uniquely.

Comment: Hint: you have 64,798 observations!

Comment: I think what @whuber is hinting at is that even tiny effects can be deemed to be statistically significant with such a large sample size.  This is where you need to take a step back and look not just at statistical significance but also at practical significance:  Is a change of -0.3 units in your dependent variable practically significant?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Makes sense. Thanks, yeah I would say a change of -0.3 is practical. The dependent variable is a score between 0-36.